# Como converter data no momento do select e retornar via Json

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, datapicker

Em meu formulário estou usando o `Bootstrap-Datepicker` para que o usuário possa informar a data desejada no momento do cadastro, funciona corretamente, mas no momento de realizar um alteração estou tentando trazer do banco a data no formato `99/99/9999` com o comando `DATE_FORMAT()` via `MySQL` e retornar os dados via `Json` mas as datas não estão sendo convertidas e não sendo posicionadas nos respectivos campos, o meu select está assim:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DataInicial,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DataInicial, DATE_FORMAT(DataFinal,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DataFinal FROM agendaMural WHERE IdAgenda = 2448
```

Mas o meu `console.log` me mostra esse resultado, as datas não estão sendo convertidas, já tentei as alternativas que conhecia, vejam como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A página com o código do retorno é essa:

```
if (jQxhr.responseText != "[]") {
    try {
        if (jQxhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (jQxhr.status === 200) {
                var nota = JSON.parse(jQxhr.responseText);
                //Atribui valores aos campos
                $('#idUnidade').val(nota[0].idUnidade);
                $('#IdDepartamento').val(nota[0].IdDepto);  
                $('#dDataInicial').val(nota[0].DataInicial);        
                $('#dDataFinal').val(nota[0].DataFinal);    
                $('#dHoraInicial').val(nota[0].HoraInicial);        
                $('#dHoraFinal').val(nota[0].HoraFinal);    
                $('#sAssunto').val(nota[0].Assunto);
                $('#sLocal').val(nota[0].Local);
                $('#sDescricao').val(nota[0].Descricao);                    
            } else {
                var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: 'ERRO',
                    type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                    message: 'Ocorreu um erro na requisição dos dados. Tente novamente.'
                }); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode formatar sua data utilizando jQuery, veja um exemplo:

```
function formatarData(data) {
    var arrData = data.split("-");
    return arrData[2] + "/" + arrData[1] + "/" arrData[0];
}  

var dataInicial = formatarData(nota[0].DataInicial);
var dataFinal = formatarData(nota[0].DataFinal);
$('#dDataInicial').val(dataInicial);
$('#dDataFinal').val(dataFinal);
```

Comment: Olá @Pedro Camara Junior, obrigado pela dica, as datas ficaram convertidas corretamente, mas as mesmas não estão sendo atribuídas aos respectivos campos, alguma dica?

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na resposta, criei uma função para retornar a data formatada.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com não estão sendo atribuídas?

Comment: Olá @Pedro Camara Junior, obrigado pela função. Ao fazer isso $("#dDataInicial").val(DataInicialFormatada); a data não está aparecendo no campo.

Comment: Mostra algum erro no console do navegador? O nome da variável está correto?

Comment: Sim, os nomes das variáveis estão corretas e nenhum erro é mostrado no console, não sei onde posso estar errando

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32044/discussion-between-pedro-camara-junior-and-adventistapr).